# How do I prevent this pointer from changing?

Tags: javascript, variables, pointers, backbone.js, reference

```
        var oldView = currentView;
        currentView = new View();
        console.log(oldView) //oldView should point to the old one, not the new one.
```

Comment: it's just a Backbone View (but it doesn't matter)

Comment: how about doing a deepcopy ?

Comment: @TIMEX: It does matter. If `currentView` is an object then it would be assigned as reference; you have to clone it.

Comment: Yes it's an object, not a Integer or anything :)

Comment: @MimiEAM I want oldView to point to the old View. I don't want to copy it

Comment: have you run that code?  what you describe should already be happening.  javascript has neither pointers nor references (in the C++ sense).

Comment: @TIMEX if you make a deep copy of the currentView (and store it into oldview) before you modify it then oldview will not change when u update the currentView

Comment: @Eevee You're right, thanks! oldView is actually pointing to the old one, not the new one.

Comment: future generations, please ignore the suggestions to deep copy.  you absolutely do not need deep copies for this; the given code already works.  deep copying should be a _last resort_ besides, not the first tool you whip out when you want to preserve data.

Comment: With 13K you should know how to ask a question that would not be deleted due to the lack of explanation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To expand on my comment:

I assume you're thinking of C++ "reference" variables.  JavaScript doesn't have these, and it doesn't have pointers either.

C++'s semantics are built around the idea of fixed memory locations: `int foo;` guarantees your program four bytes somewhere.  `foo` will always refer to those same four bytes.  If you then create a *reference* to `foo` with `int &bar = foo;`, `bar` will also always refer to those same four bytes.  Whatever value is assigned to one variable will be the value you get from the other.

JavaScript, like many other dynamic languages, doesn't work like this.  Variable names are more like labels that are moved between objects, and the precise details of where the objects live is none of your business.  So, step by step, your code does this:

```
var oldView = currentView;
```

Create a name, `oldView`, and stick it to the same object `currentView` is stuck to.  Like a post-it note.

```
currentView = new View();
```

Create a new `View` object, and stick the name `currentView` on it.  This will have *no effect* on `oldView`; that's an entirely different name, still stuck to the same object.

```
console.log(oldView);
```

Because you never changed `oldView`, it's still attached to the same object.